# Error : java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer When running TFS-SDK in Java Web Application

Tags: java, tomcat, tfs

I am using TFS-SDK for my Java application. First I created a simple Java project to test it. So I downloaded the [JAR from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616). The code also I got the code from [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-a-java-sdk-for-tfs.aspx). I am using Ubuntu. So in my Java code I added the following codes to load the native library

```
System.load("/home/myfolder/Documents/TFS-SDK-11.0.0/redist/native/linux/x86_64/libnative_auth.so");        
System.load("/home/myfolder/Documents/TFS-SDK-11.0.0/redist/native/linux/x86_64/libnative_console.so");     
System.load("/home/myfolder/Documents/TFS-SDK-11.0.0/redist/native/linux/x86_64/libnative_filesystem.so");      
System.load("/home/myfolder/Documents/TFS-SDK-11.0.0/redist/native/linux/x86_64/libnative_misc.so");        
System.load("/home/myfolder/Documents/TFS-SDK-11.0.0/redist/native/linux/x86_64/libnative_synchronization.so");
```

When I run the query, I am getting the output fine.

I added the same code in my Web application. The method is calling from my action class. In tomcat, when it is running I am getting exception.

```
ERROR [tomcat-http--27] AAIDCATeamFoundationAction.handleException(11) | java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer   
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.internal.db.DBStatement.executeIntQuery(DBStatement.java:261) at com.microsoft.tfs.core.internal.db.HSQLOperations.tableExists(HSQLOperations.java:23)    
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.metadata.Metadata$1.performTask(Metadata.java:165)  at com.microsoft.tfs.core.internal.db.ConnectionPool.executeWithPooledConnection(ConnectionPool.java:80)    
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.metadata.Metadata.<init>(Metadata.java:139) at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.WITContext.<init>(WITContext.java:100)  
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.WorkItemClient.getContext(WorkItemClient.java:423)   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.WorkItemClient.query(WorkItemClient.java:589)    
at com.app.dca.adapters.TFSDataCollector.getTFSData(TFSDataCollector.java:41)   at com.app.webapp.action.AAIDCATeamFoundationAction.execute(AAIDCATeamFoundationAction.java:90) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:446)   
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:285)   
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)   
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)  
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)  at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)   
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)    
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)   
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)   
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)    
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)    
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242) at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) 
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)  at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)  at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:88)    
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)   
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)    
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:82)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)    
at com.app.webapp.filter.RequestAuthentication.doFilter(RequestAuthentication.java:57)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)    
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)  at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)  at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)    at com.app.webapp.filter.RequestAuthentication.doFilter(RequestAuthentication.java:57)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

The line number (TFSDataCollector.java:41) refers to

```
WorkItemCollection workItems = workItemClient.query(wiqlQuery);
```

Then I removed thye above System.load statements and in tomcat catalina.sh I added the following code

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory=/home/myfolder/Documents/TFS-SDK-11.0.0/redist/native"
```

And again I am getting the same error. What can be the reason and how can I solve this?

Comment: What is the content of wiqlQuery and what is the datamodel of the underlying table?

Comment: @SubOptimal if you see the blog link i given, there is example Java program. The query is a select query.
`String wiqlQuery = "Select ID, Title from WorkItems where (State = 'Active') order by Title";`
I don't know the data model of table. Because like in the demo program, I have given the tfs url, and credentials(which I cannot give here). I tried omitting the `ID` from query. Then also its getting same rror

Comment: Based on the javadoc of the entity `WorkItems` the property ID is of type `int`. Releated to your posted exception and the [supported datatypes in HSQLDB](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#datatypes-section) seems in the related table of the entity the ID column is created as BIGINT. I don't know if this might be releated to a specific version of the TFS. If you have the possibility try to verify it with a 90-day trial of a different TFS version.